# JavaScript API -- support for IE 5.5 onwards

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

Hi: jQuery spoiled me a lot ;-) I am one of the early adapters of jQuery and I can't think anything other than that. Recently I am involving in a project, where I need to support any browsers, say from IE 5.5 onwards. Is there any other JavaScript API supports IE 5.5?

I know what you are thinking about IE 5.5, some of the end users are poor non-profit organizations which don't have enough budget to upgrade to latest. So I don't have a choice here. Please let me know your thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at BBC Glow:  http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/

Comment: Why has the BBC made a javascript library??

Comment: @Eric: This might help explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098560/marginal-browser-support-by-the-bbc-and-why-the-bbc-they-cant-use-jquery